# Xampp: Increase the File import limit from 2048 kb to 500Mb and also Time limit from 5 min to 30Min in the Xampp (lampp)

Tags: php, xampp

I am using Xampp in ubuntu 14.04.1. I want to increase the limit of File_Upload from 2,048KiB to 500MB.

I have used the following:
changes in file php.ini

```
post_max_size = 750M 
upload_max_filesize = 750M 
max_execution_time = 5000 
max_input_time = 5000 
memory_limit = 1000M
```

but nothing worked.

can any one tell me what else changes should be done?

Xammp: 7.0.3
OS: Ubuntu 14.x

Comment: Check the output of `phpinfo()` for the proper path of php.ini; some systems have many copies of it and you may not be editing the right one. According to https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#i-cannot-upload-big-dump-files-memory-http-or-timeout-problems it does look like you're editing the correct values and haven't missed anything, so I'd start with making sure it's the correct php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

For increase in Upload filesize Limit:

make changes in `/opt/lampp/etc/php.in`

open the php.ini with sudoedit. the find the MB displayed in File upload limit in Xampp. Search in php.ini.

I have make changes in:

```
post_max_size=1800M
upload_max_filesize=1800M
memory_limit=2000M
```

still don't known how to increase time limit

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question - but this worked for me and may be useful for someone else searching for an answer.

Open your xampp install folder and go to php folder. With some text editor file (notepad++) open the file called *php.ini* (by type windows describes it as configuration settings) and edit the line (cca. 770, or press ctrl+f  in notepad++ to find it):

```
post_max_size = 2M
```

instead `2M`, put wanted maximum file size (`16MB` for example but not higher than `128M`), after that go to this line:

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

instead `30`, increase execution time that’s in seconds (`90` for example), also you need to change this line:

```
max_input_time = 60
```

instead `60`, increase input time in seconds (`120` for example)

and top of all you have to change this line:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

instead of `2M`, increase to `16M` for example.

Save the file, restart apache and mysql in xampp and try to upload again, if you follow correctly you should be able to import files through 16MB (example)

You must pay attention to following:

1. If the `upload_max_filesize` is larger than `post_max_size`, you must increase `post_max_size` so that it is bigger than `upload_max_size`.
2. If the value of `post_max_size` is larger than `memory_limit`, you must increase `memory_limit` so that it is larger than `post_max_size`.
3. You MUST SHUT DOWN AND RESTART XAMPP FOR THE NEW PROCESS TO WORK.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP 7.1.31 for windows.

Your php directory

```
C:\xampp\php
```

edit php.ini to something like this

```
post_max_size=64M
upload_max_filesize=64M
memory_limit=512M
```